# Laravel CURL - Passing a string to HTTP URL (Postfields)

Tags: php, laravel, curl, postdata

I use Laravel 9 and the built-in method **Http::withHeaders ($headers)->post($url, $data)**.

In the $data variable, I pass the string that resulted from http_build_request with the "&" separator. But Laravel tries to make an array out of it and send data.

The API service returns me an error. Please tell me how you can force Laravel to pass exactly a STRING(!), and not an array?

My code:

```
$array = [
            'key1' => 'value1',
            'key2' => 'value2',
            // etc...
];
$headers = [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'HMAC' => $hmac
];

$data = http_build_query($array, '', '&');
$response = Http::withHeaders($headers)->post($api_url, $data);
return json_decode($response->getBody()));
```

Comment: If I use native PHP and curl_init() with parameters, then everything is fine. But I would like to implement this solution exclusively by the built-in method Http::post () which contains Laravel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried, `asForm`?

```
$response = Http::withHeaders($headers)->asForm()->post($api_url, $data);
```

If you would like to send data using the application/x-www-form-urlencoded content type, you should call the asForm method before making your request.

Comment: Thank you friend, you are the best! It worked. Only first I had to remove http_build_query and everything works fine!

Comment: @ForceMan glad it helped. good luck.

Answer (score 2):

If you sending it as x-www-form-urlencoded i gues u should be able to pass the data inside request body.

```
 $response = Http::withHeaders($headers)
      ->withBody($data)
      ->asForm()
      ->post($api_url);
```

however, i am not sure if this will work